# How Do I Show a Static List of Countries Without Using an Accordion?

Tags: data, accordion, country

I make a new web application.

My web application shows the Country property with an accordion. I want to find a new way for showing this data.  Because all countries, amounting to 190, is a lot of data. Accordions are not an option for this.

All Countries have children which are networks, and all Networks have children which are four services.  Services colors will be red or green.

**Scenarios** :

If one of the services is red, and another service is green, the Network will be yellow.
If all services are red, Parent will be red.
If all services are green, Network(Parent) will be green.

like this :

http://jsfiddle.net/mehmetakifalp/ZSEhP/

Here's a basic **wireframe**,
    [image]
I hope you understand me.

*Country
Network(Parent)
Services(Property, child)*

Comment: You can load the sub-items data dynamically, according to the user's choice of parent item and display it all in one dynamic combobox. You could use a dynamic combobox for this e.g. select2: http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/

Comment: I second the combobox idea. Create the network combobox based on the country combobox selection and populate a multi-checkbox input for the services. Save a ton of space and it would look tidy.

Comment: If interaction assumes working with single country each time, you could significantly simplify interface: 1) Select country, 2) Edit parameters.

Comment: Thank you for all comment. @AlexeyKolchenko;okey but,  If I want to see all country, how can I do this?  @DannyVarod; thank you for plugin, But I cant use this kind solution... I have to find a different way..

Comment: If you work with one country setting its parameters, the Master-Detail pattern could help. You can easy switch between countries and edit parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use Master-detail pattern.
[image]

To quick countries view you could use additional information in the country list.
[image]

Comment: Hey Alexey Kolchenko, thank you. Its really good idea. I will try.